# Listing all packages in given repository

Tags: r

How to list all packages available in given repository or list all packages available without using list from : http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `available.packages()` to do this.

Try, for example:

```
options(repos = "http://cran.revolutionanalytics.com")
p <- available.packages()
head(p)
```

To extract the package names, get the column called "Package".

```
head(p[, "Package"])
           A3   ABCExtremes      ABCoptim         ABCp2        ACCLMA           ACD 
         "A3" "ABCExtremes"    "ABCoptim"       "ABCp2"      "ACCLMA"         "ACD"
```

Comment: specifically (if you just want the list), `ap <- available.packages(); rownames(ap)`

Comment: or `available.packages(contriburl=contrib.url(http://cran.revolutionanalytics.com"))`  (clunky, but that's the way it is)

Comment: @BenBolker It's a bit more reliable to extract the "Packages" column, since in some situations the `rownames` can also contain a prefix, specifically containing some repos information.

Comment: OK.  I still prefer using `contriburl` rather than globally setting the `repos` option ...